# how to connect docker swarm worker to swarm manager - AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

I am unable to connect my docker worker to docker swam manager.

I have created multiple aws EC2 instances and have made one of them as a manager `docker swarm init --listen-addr 0.0.0.0:2377` and trying to connect it via other EC2 instances `docker swarm join 0.0.0.0:2377` as a worker, But it gives me an error.

```
 "Error response from daemon: Timeout was reached before node joined`. 
The attempt to join the swarm will continue in the background".
```

I need my docker swarm manager to list `docker node ls` all the nodes including manager and workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this problem I needed to expose respective ports from both Docker Worker and Docker Manager instances.

I discovered some information while resolving this question,

**TCP Port 2377** is a Default port used for communication so add custom tcp rule for port 2377 in security group of aws EC2.

**TCP port 2376** for secure Docker client communication. This port is required for Docker Machine to work. Docker Machine is used to orchestrate Docker hosts.

**TCP port 2377** This port is used for communication between the nodes of a Docker Swarm or cluster. It only needs to be opened on manager nodes.

**TCP and UDP port 7946** for communication among nodes (container network discovery).

**UDP port 4789** for overlay network traffic (container ingress networking).

**Kindly Note:** Aside from those ports, **port 22 (for SSH traffic)** and any other ports needed for specific services to run on the cluster have to be open.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the real ip address in the `docker swarm join` command.

The "0.0.0.0" is not a real ip-address, it's an alias for "all (local) ip-addresses", it's not something you can connect to.

Comment: I have already used real public IP address of my ec2 instance to connect. I just want to keep it private so I wrote 0.0.0.0

Comment: Then please don't use 0.0.0.0, it confuses network people :)

Comment: Are your EC2 instances in the same VPC? If so, you should be able to use the internal address.

Answer (score 0):

1.run the command in the master node:
docker swarm join-token worker

2.and than run the command obtained from above step

example:

root@ubuntu:~# docker swarm join-token worker
To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

```
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-0akniaryx9xg8mmb08rbd42kwntigfkyk33vt7ac0wrehn58mk-5voo7jfl3kl40yl4cmvf16lgt 10.0.10.4:2377
```

root@ubuntu:~#

run on worker node:
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-0akniaryx9xg8mmb08rbd42kwntigfkyk33vt7ac0wrehn58mk-5voo7jfl3kl40yl4cmvf16lgt 10.0.10.4:2377